# Como actualizo un campo Input al escribir un monto se actualize la cantidad en otro input?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Como actualizo un campo Input al escribir un monto se actualize la cantidad en otro input?

si secribo en este campo de mi archivo index.php:

```
    <?php
    <input type="number" name="usd">
    // me gustaria que este campo tome la variable 
//de el archivo btc.php de manera automatica actulize su valor en BTC
    <input type="number" name="btc">
    ?>
```

quisiera que este campo me tome la variable de otro BTC.php  la variable:

```
<?php
    $url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/";
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/',true);
    $json=json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"utf-8");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    // variable a tomar--->>> $price_usd;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer con ajax asi lo puedes mejorar creando un archivo js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="usd" id="usd" placeholder="usd" oninput="procesar()">

        <input type="number" name="btc" id="btc" placeholder="btc">
    </form>


<script>
    function procesar(){
        var usd = document.querySelector('#usd').value;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET','https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/',true);
        xhr.onload=function(){
            if(this.status==200){
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                
                var price_usd = response[0].price_usd;
                document.querySelector('#btc').value = price_usd;

            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lo ejecute aqui en respuesta no me corrio lo hice en mi zampp tampoco xq?

Comment: a mi me funciona perfectamente intenta de nuevo

Comment: solo un error creo que convierte invertido

Comment: veo que funciona pero solo saca el valor de uno si quiero sacar cuanto vale 100 USD en BTC

Comment: ya tendrias que mirar que parametros recibe el api por que la url que tienes solo muestra datos